# Topology, compact

Tags: general-topology

I have had some problems to solve the following question : Is there a continuous bijection of a compact Hausdorff space over the space of rational numbers?
I think the answer should be no, it has cost me a lot to find a counterexample
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean is there a continuous bijection $X\to\mathbb{Q}$ when $X$ is Hausdorff and compact? The answer is no. A continuous bijection from a compact space to a Hausdorff space is a homeomorphism. A compact topological space can't be homeomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$ with the standard topology. (since $\mathbb{Q}$ is not compact)

Comment: Thank you very much, I knew that result but I thought it was not applicable under certain hypotheses, now it has become clear to me